# Translation of custom validator in php template

Tags: symfony, translation

I do built me a custom constraint validator. The validator is working. But how can I translate the error messages of the CUSTOM validator in a php template? The other validator messages are working, so I do have the translation in `app/config/validators.XX.yml`.

In my action:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
             ->add('date_id', 'choice', array(
                ....
                'constraints' => array(new CheckChoicesDateId(array('date_ids' => $date_ids))),
                ....
            ))
```

in Bundle/Validator/Constraints

```
class CheckChoicesDateId extends Constraint
{
    public $invalidMessage = '{{ value }}';
    public $date_ids;
    public function __construct($options = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($options);

        if (null === $this->date_ids ) {
            throw new MissingOptionsException('Option date_ids must be given for constraint ' . __CLASS__, array('date_ids'));
        }
    }
}
```

in Bundle/Validator/Constraints

```
class CheckChoicesDateIdValidator extends ConstraintValidator {

    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint) {

        if ($value == NULL || !isset($value)) {
            $this->context->addViolation($constraint->invalidMessage, array(
                '{{ value }}' => 'error.date.0',
                //I also tried $this->get('translator')->trans('error.date.0');
                // with the error message: Call to undefined method GET
            ));
        }


        if (is_numeric($value)) {
            $t = array_key_exists($value, $constraint->date_ids);
            if ($t == NULL) {
                $this->context->addViolation($constraint->invalidMessage, array(
                    '{{ value }}' => 'error.date.1',
                ));
            }
        }
        return;
    }

}
```

In my template:

```
<?php echo $view['form']->errors($form['date_id']) ?>
//I also tried
<?php echo $this->get('translator')->trans($view['form']->errors($form['date_id'])) ?>
```

Comment: Put your `validators.XX.yml` in `app/Resources/{your_bundle}/transalations/` or `src/your/bundle/Resources/transalition/`.

Comment: I did. But it doesn't help. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hey, if you are interested, I posted a solution. Thanks anyway for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

I do have a solution, but I guess it is not nice:

In the action I do pass for each possible error a variable.

```
'constraints' => array(new CheckChoicesDateId(array('date_ids' => $date_ids, 'error_date_0 => $this->get('translator')...., 'error_date_1 => $this->get('translator')....  ))),
```

and in the custom validator I call for each error the right variable with `$constraint->error_date_X`.

Not nice, but it is working. If anybody has a better solution, feel free to post it!